# How to get data from local storage using LOGIN form in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

```js
const firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
const lastnName = document.getElementById("lastName");
const email = document.getElementById("newEmail");
const password = document.getElementById("newPassword");

const btnSignup = document.getElementById("btn-signup");

function signUp() { // when mouse click "signup" button
    const first_name = firstName.value; // getting the value of firstName and so on..
    const last_name = lastName.value;
    const e_mail = newEmail.value;
    const pass_word = newPassword.value;

    // if the fields are empty
    if (!first_name || !last_name || !e_mail || !pass_word) {
        return alert("you need to fill up all the forms.");
    }
    //set user input into JSON
    let user_data = {
        firstName: first_name,
        lastName: last_name,
        email: e_mail,
        password: pass_word
    }

    //convert to string
    let user_data_str = JSON.stringify(user_data);

    //get to localstorage if there is existing user ||or make empty array[]
    let clientsArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || [];

    // search the list if
    const userExists = clientsArr.find(user => JSON.stringify(user) === user_data_str);
    if (userExists) {
        return alert("User already Exists");
    }

    //push new user to array
    clientsArr.push(user_data);

    //save to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(clientsArr));
    return alert("Account Created!");

}
// attach listener
btnSignup.addEventListener("click", signUp);
```

This is the code that I created in registering users inside the localstorage, it's working actually, my problem is, how can I use that information when using the login form? thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please also put the HTML mark up so that we can create another snippets or working code around it?

Comment: stackoverflow not letting me because of too much code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

- get `email` and `password` as an input from the user.
- retrieve the user by email from the `localStorage` .
- if exists, compare `password`.

```js
// email && password are <input /> fields
const email = document.getElementById("loginEmail");
const password = document.getElementById("loginPassword");

const btnSignin = document.getElementById("btn-signin");

function signIn() { 
    const users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
    const user = users.find(u => u.email === email.value);
    
    if (user) {
      if (user.password === password.value) {
        alert("Wellcome " + user.firstName);
      } else {
        alert("Wrong password.");
      }
    } else {
      alert("User deos not exist.");
    }
}

btnSignin.addEventListener("click", signIn);
```

Comment: I will try this one pain when I got home, i'll update in the comment if it's done :) thanks!